# Pointing external url to my application load balancer in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

So we want to point an external url to the load balancer in aws and then load balancer will redirect it to an Internal app server.
I have set up the listener configuration and load balancer is now redirecting the traffic to app server but external url is still not pointing to ELB.
I have already set up the Route 53 record.
Any suggestions please.
Thanks